# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sparse'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to one-hot-encoding the columns of an array using the OneHotEncoder in sklearn, but I encontered the following error:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sparse'`

Here is my code :

```
a = np.array([[2, 3, 5], [4, 6, 8], [3, 7, 32]], dtype=np.uint8)
catego_features_idx = [0, 1, 2]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)

ohe = ColumnTransformer([
    ("One_hot_encoder", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, categories='auto'), catego_features_idx)
], remainder='passthrough')  # ColumnTransformer(List of (name, transformer, columns) tuples)
df1 = ohe.fit_transform(df1.values)
print(df1)
```

sklearn version is 0.23.1.

How could I resolve the above error and achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete code that I was able to run on sklearn == 0.23.1

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3, 5], [4, 6, 8], [3, 7, 32]])
catego_features_idx = [0, 1, 2]

ohe = ColumnTransformer([
        ("One_hot_encoder", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, categories='auto'), 
         catego_features_idx)
                        ], remainder='passthrough')

print(ohe.fit_transform(df.values))
```

This produces the below without an error.

```
[[1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved for me by deleting the following code:

`from category_encoders import *`

I guess this is probably because the `One-hot-encoder` in `category_encoders` module has override the `One-hot-encoder` in `sklearn.preprocessing`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sklearn version

```
import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)
```

if greater than 0.2.7 remove argument like sparse

```
   OH_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse_output=False)
   OH_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
```